# DevExpress XtraReport not created in Visual studio?

Tags: devexpress, addition, xtrareport

I am doing a Master-Detail report by XtraReport using Entity Framework as datasource, when I add (Add New Item) the XtraReport1, its woking (created). But when I add the second XtraReport, after select connection and Entity object, everything looked ok as well, but the XtraReport file doesn't created. There are no error, nothing, just the report was not created. I am crazy with it
Visual studio 2013
Devexpress 14.1.4

Answer (score 1):

If you like to create a master-detail report using entity framework classes then  review this thread -  [Data Binding - Entity Framework and Linq to SQL support (Relations)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S30767.aspx) and if you want to dig more about assignment of collection data source in Master-Detail then check [How to create a hierarchical master-detail datasource](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E137.aspx) example illustrating how to accomplish.

References:
[xtrareport x entity framework](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q338037)
[How to create a hierarchical master-detail datasource](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E137)
 [Data Binding - Entity Framework and Linq to SQL support (Relations)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S30767)

You can find lots of thread regarding this on [DevExpress Search - XtraReport entity framwork](https://search.devexpress.com/default.aspx?page=2&q=xtrareports%20entity%20framework)